# Array of sockets as a parameters in CreateThread

Tags: c++, multithreading, winsock

I have an exmaple wich describes how to send 1 socket as a parameter to the new thread.

```
SOCKET clientSocket;
 ...

CreateThread(NULL, NULL, SexToClient, &clientSocket, NULL, &thID);
      ...}


DWORD WINAPI SexToClient(LPVOID client) {
    SOCKET clientSocket;
    clientSocket = ((SOCKET*)client)[0];
        ...   }
```

But now I want to make another thread with array of sockets. How can I send them and use in thread?

And what does mean [0] at the end of this line? In this particular example we're send only one socket and it's working fine.

```
((SOCKET*)client)[0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass any arguments to the CreateThread method by wrapping all the arguments into simple structure. For example:

```
struct ThreadParams {
    std::vector<SOCKET *> sockets;
    std::string clientName;
    // more params
};
```

All you need to do is to initialize this structure before calling CreateThread function, and then pass a pointer:

```
ThreadParams * params = new ThreadParams();
params.setParameters();
CreateThread(, , SexToClient, params, );

DWORD WINAPI SexToClient(LPVOID arg) {
    ThreadParams * params = reinterpret_cast<ThreadParams *>(arg);
    // delete after usage;
    delete params;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call CreateThread as many times as you want with different data as the fourth parameters and the new thread will get that data.

```
((SOCKET*)client)[0]
```

just grabs the first element.  It casts it to a SOCKET pointer then grabs the first element.  This is another way to write

```
*(SOCKET *)client;
```